# Extract item for each spider in scrapy project

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have over a dozen spiders in a scrapy project with variety of items being extracted from different sources, including others elements mostly i have to copy same regex code over and over again in each spider for example

```
item['element'] = re.findall('my_regex', response.text)
```

I use this regex to get same element which is defined in scrapy items, is there a way to avoid copying? where do i put this in project so that i don't have to copy this in each spider and only add those that are different.

my project structure is default

**any help is appreciated thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you try to regex from pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can copy regex in multiple spiders instead of importing object from other .py files, i understand they have the use case but here i don't want to add anything to any of the spiders but still want the element in result

There are some good answers to this but don't really solve the problem so after searching for days i have come to this solution i hope its useful for others looking for similar answer.

```
#middlewares.py
import yourproject.items import youritem()
#find the function and add your element 

def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    item = YourItem()
    item['element'] = re.findall('my_regex', response.text)
```

now uncomment middleware from

```
#settings.py

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'yourproject.middlewares.YoursprojectMiddleware': 543,
}
```

For each spider you will get element in result data, i am still searching for better solution and i will update the answer because it slows the spider,

Comment: Can you please explain your code, because `process_spider_output` seems that it is related to a `Class`, because of `self`, but there is no `Class`.   One of your input is `spider` and another is `results`, but neither are used in your function.  How are these inputs being used?  Also how is `SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES` used in your code?

Comment: This is not the complete middlewares.py file, if you see your default middleware.py file you would understand its just that part of middleware

Comment: It's not clear how you solved your problem with the code you provides, so it's unclear "this solution <will be> useful for others looking for similar answer."  That is why I'm asking you to expand on your answer.

Comment: What i want? I use same regex to get element in response.text regardless of website i am scraping so the problem is i dont want to copy same regex in 50+ spiders since files like settings.py, middleware.py pipeline.py etc are same for all 50+ spiders so if i add something there it would be applied to all 50+ spiders so i added regex in middlewares this way i get element in output… i hope it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand your question correctly, you want use the same regular expression across multiple spiders.

You can do this:

- create a python module called something like `regex_to_use`
- inside that module place your regular expression.

example:

```
# regex_to_use.py

regex_one = 'test'
```

You can access this express this one in your spiders.

```
# spider.py

import regex_to_use
import re as regex

find_string = regex.search(regex_to_use.regex_one, ' this is a test')
print(find_string)
# output 
<re.Match object; span=(11, 15), match='test'>
```

You could also do something like this in your `regex_to_use` module

```
# regex_to_use.py

import re as regex

class CustomRegularExpressions(object):
    
    def __init__(self, text):
        """
        :param text: string containing the variable to search for
        """
        self._text = text

    def search_text(self):
        find_xyx = regex.search('test', self._text)
        return find_xyx
```

and you would call it this way in your spiders:

```
# spider.py

from regex_to_use import CustomRegularExpressions


find_word = CustomRegularExpressions('this is a test').search_text()
print(find_word)
# output
<re.Match object; span=(10, 14), match='test'>
```

If you have multiple regular expressions you could do something like this:

```
# regex_to_use.py

import re as regex

class CustomRegularExpressions(object):

    def __init__(self, text):
        """
        :param text: string containing the variable to search for
        """
        self._text = text

    def search_text(self, regex_to_use):
        regular_expressions = {"regex_one": 'test_1', "regex_two": 'test_2'}
        expression = ''.join([v for k, v in regular_expressions.items() if k == regex_to_use])
        find_xyx = regex.search(expression, self._text)
        return find_xyx
```

```
# spider.py

from regex_to_use import CustomRegularExpressions

find_word = CustomRegularExpressions('this is a test').search_text('regex_one')
print(find_word)
# output
<re.Match object; span=(10, 14), match='test'>
```

You can also use a `staticmethod` in the class `CustomRegularExpressions`

```
# regex_to_use.py

import re as regex

class CustomRegularExpressions:

    @staticmethod
    def search_text(regex_to_use, text_to_search):
        regular_expressions = {"regex_one": 'test_1', "regex_two": 'test_2'}
        expression = ''.join([v for k, v in regular_expressions.items() if k == regex_to_use])
        find_xyx = regex.search(expression, text_to_search)
        return find_xyx
```

```
# spider.py

from regex_to_use import CustomRegularExpressions

# find_word would be replaced with item['element'] 
# this is a test would be replaced with response.text
find_word = CustomRegularExpressions.search_text('regex_one', 'this is a test')
print(find_word)
# output
<re.Match object; span=(10, 14), match='test'>
```

If you use docstrings in the function `search_text()` you can see the regular expressions in the Python dictionary.

[image]

***Showing how all this works...***

This is a [python project](https://github.com/johnbumgarner/wordhoard/tree/master/wordhoard) that I wrote and published. Take a look at the folder utilities.  In this folder I have functions that I can use throughout my code without having to *copy and paste* the same code over and over.

Comment: Where did you get this answer from lol, [there is no way you managed to write this answer in less than a minute XD]

Comment: I wrote this answer in pycharm.  I use these types of features in my projects all the time.  Such classes and functions save me a ton of time.  For example, BeautifulSoup  is one package I use often, I wrote a class that I use across all my scrapers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of common data that is usual to use across multiple spiders, like `regex` or even `XPath`.

It's a good idea to isolate them.

You can use something like this:

```
/project
    /site_data
        handle_responses.py
        ...
    /spiders
        your_spider.py
        ...
```

Isolate functionalities with a common purpose.

```
# handle_responses.py

# imports ...
from re import search


def get_specific_commom_data(text: str):
    # probably is a good idea handle predictable errors here (`try except`) 
    return search('your_regex', text)
```

And just use where is needed that functionality.

```
# your_spider.py

# imports ...
import scrapy
from site_data.handle_responses import get_specific_commom_data


class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # ... previous code
    def your_method(self, response):
        # ... previous code
        item['element'] = get_specific_commom_data(response.text)
```

Try to keep it simple and do what you need to solve your problem.